# How do I get this if else statement to work with a String variable? (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, public-method

The script below is a test script and I can get the if else to run when the variable is an int. But I can't seem to get it to run the if else statement when a string is entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifelse
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

      String money;

      System.out.println("Enter how much money you have.");
      money = keyboard.nextLine();

      if (money == "fifty"){

      System.out.println("money");
      }
      else if(money == "seventy"){
      System.out.println("Nothing");
      }
   }
}
```

The code below works and it's using int for the variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifelse
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

      int money;

      System.out.println("Enter how much money you have.");
      money = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (money == 50){

      System.out.println("money");
      }
      else if(money == 70){
      System.out.println("Nothing");
      }
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare `Strings` with `.equals` function, not with `==`.

```
if(money.equals("fifty")){
 //Code
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 Better yet, mention that you use .equals for any Objects.

Comment: @Gamma2626 I guess he is a totally beginner so I think it is better simplify it for not confuse him.

Comment: Great! worked perfect! I had to add an extra ")" at the end of the statement. Appreciate it, could not find a clear answer online.

Comment: Missing a closing `)` in your answer

Comment: @d_ominic For sure. Just a mistake. Thanks for the point!

Comment: This answer adds nothing compared to the much more informative answers in the canonical post. If you have new information to add on the subject, add it there in order to avoid fragmentation.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Oh, it wasn't my purpose to fragment the information. I really don't have new information about that but I adapted the function to the OP question. Maybe it could help a little bit more to him.